# For who or For whom

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, relative-pronouns, who-whom, subject-vs-object-pronouns

What is the correct usage in the sentence:

“I am the one for who / whom the cafe was kept open.”

Since who / whom refers to the subject “I”, would the subjective case “who” be correct?

Comment: @BMofSpadana: yes, but without the comma.

Comment: @BMofSpadana: No, the misplaced comma and ending a sentence on a preposition make for a worse sentence than simply misusing “whom.”

Comment: @cosmic, there is nothing at all wrong with ending a sentence on a preposition. The misplaced comma can and should be removed, leaving "*I'm the one the cafe was kept open for.*" as a better choice. Or "person" could be used in place of "one". Or one could say "*The cafe was kept open for me*" which is shorter and avoids the final preposition.

Comment: Or you can simply say, "I'm the one the café was kept open for.

Answer (score 13):

While "I" is the subject of the *main clause*, "who/whom" is part of the *relative clause*, and refers to the object of the preposition "for". The subject of that clause is "the cafe", not "I".

It's easier to see if we split the two clauses in your sentence into two separate sentences. It now looks something like this:

> I am the one. The cafe was kept open for **me**.

"The cafe" is the subject of the clause with "for me". The word "me" is the object of "for". To connect the two clauses, we first replace "me" with an appropriate relative pronoun:

> I am the one. The cafe was kept open for **whom**.

"Whom" is appropriate here because it's the object of the preposition "for", and "for who" is bad grammar.

Next, we move "for" and its relative pronoun object to the front of the clause:

> I am the one **for whom** the cafe was kept open.

Although "I" and "whom" happen to mean the same person, grammatically they are two different nouns from different clauses.

Comment: Thank you! I knew “whom” was correct and that the sentence could have been framed differently  to avoid the use of who/whom altogether. But I read this sentence construction somewhere and wondered why it was correct. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 9):

"Whom" is the technically correct word in this construction, as [the answer by user gotube](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/307498/91457) explains. But "whom" is rapidly becoming  obsolete. Many native speakers no longer use it in any construction. Thus I would suggest rewording this without "whom" such as:

> I am the one that the cafe was kept open for.

This carries the same meaning and avoids the who/whom issue.

Particularly in speech one will often hear fluent and native speakers use "who" where "whom" is grammatically called for. One should be ready to accept and understand such usage, and it may become standard within the lifetime of people currently adult. In informal speech, it is probably best to avoid "whom" totally, as some will (wrongly) consider it affected or pompous.

Comment: Great point. In fact, in the OP's example sentence is a case in point for the disappearance of "whom". If we only front "who/whom", and leave the "for" at the end of the sentence -- which is more common in modern English -- we get, "*I am the one **who OR whom** the cafe was kept open **for***. Grammatically, it should be "whom", but because people find "whom" pompous, "who" is acceptable.

Comment: @gotube I usually come across *who/whom* sentences where a preposition is placed just before the relative pronoun as long as it is *whom* (*I am the one **for whom** the cafe was kept open*), and at the end of the sentence otherwise (*I am the one **who** the cafe was kept open **for***). Isn't there any difference if we use *for who* in this case?

Comment: I'd go even further than saying whom is rapidly becoming obsolete and say it already is in actual speech and informal writing, just with formal styleguides lagging behind usage as usual. For the given sentence, I'd probably drop the relativiser entirely going for "I am the one the cafe was kept open for" , or even "the cafe was kept open for me"

Comment: @Mergasov "for who" (together) is always incorrect.

Comment: @Tristan "Obsolete" is a big word. People still do use "whom", and though it may sound old-fashioned, we cannot say it's obsolete until people no longer use it at all.

Comment: @gotube **I** use wherefore. In fact I use it a good deal more than I do "whom". You also write that "*"for who" (together) is always incorrect.*" On what basis? Native speakers do use that construction. To a pure descriptivist that makes it correct by definition. Or are there some prescriptive rules that still apply? If so, how does one distinguish such rules?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Other than in formal writing, I don't acknowledge any prescriptivist rules. To my ears, "for who" is as wrong as "she am...", and I'd thought it was the same for everyone. Same with "wherefore". I haven't seen or heard it in anything less than 100 years old. But if native speakers still use "for who" and "wherefore", then I'm wrong about that, and thanks for pointing it out. Can you give examples of "wherefore" and "for who" in natural modern language?

Comment: @gotube
 I will have to think some about "for who" I don't normally use it myself. I have used "wherefore" In drafting formal resolutions for a municipal council, which I was asking them to adopt. I have also used it in various more or less legalistic writings, including I think on law.se.  I have also used it in literary criticism "Now, wherefore can we conclude that Joe was jealous of Betty".

Comment: @gotube I hear “For who” in conversational contexts like  *- I will join the army! - But for who? No one in your country even likes you.* You think it is “wrong” in this kind of conversational context? I think it is probably not used even by “uneducated” native speakers though in full constructions like *People for who I joined the army don’t even like me!* I am not sure though.

Comment: @FireandIce Yep, sounds natural enough to me

Answer (score 3):

No, "whom" is correct.

"Who" is the nominative case—it is used when the word itself is the subject, such as in the sentence "Who is that man?"

All other cases of the word use "whom," as in "For whom was the store kept open?" ("the store" being the subject of that sentence).

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone will correct me if I am wrong, but I was under the impression that "for" is a "dative preposition" in English, so that every time a noun phrase follows "for", it will be in the dative case, i.e. you will always use "whom", never "who", every time it follows "for".

This might be me projecting my high-school-level German classes onto English too much, though?